# R Word Count - matching all combination of one string in another string

Tags: r

I am trying to count all combinations of matching/fuzzy matching first string column to second string column in a data frame

Eg:
string1 = "USA Canada UK Australia Japan India"
string2 = "USA Canada India UK Australia China Brazil France"

Expected results

- Single word match count = 5 (USA Canada UK Australia India) matched
- Two word match count = 2 (USA Canada, UK Australia) consecutive words matched
- Three word match count = 0
- Four word match count = 0
- Five word match count = 0
- Six word match count = 0
- In total = 5 + 2 = 7

Thank you for your time and great someone can help to write this function or point me to use any existing package

Comment: look for `ngram` in package `tm` and `quanteda`

Comment: A naive version of single word matching - `intersect(strsplit(string1, "\\s+")[[1]], strsplit(string2, "\\s+")[[1]])` - but you're probably better off using a formal package.

Comment: Thank you HubertL for the package reference

Comment: Not sure, why down votes for the question. Is it really a bad/basic question or repeated question on this topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
string1 <- "USA Canada UK Australia Japan India" 
string2 <- "USA Canada India UK Australia China Brazil France"

str1 <- unlist(strsplit(string1, " "))

library(ngram)
for(i in 1:length(str1)){
  ng1 <- ngram_asweka(string1, min = i, max = i, sep = " ")
  ng2 <- ngram_asweka(string2, min = i, max = i, sep = " ")
  print(paste(i, "word match count", length(which(ng1 %in% ng2)), sep=" "))
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, working for me